# Extracting URLs from page?

Tags: python, xpath

I've been tearing my hair out playing with variations on this:

```
'//*[@id="mw-content-text"]/div[2]/table/tbody/tr/td/div/ul/li/a'
```

as an XPath to get all of the school district urls from this wiki page: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_school_districts_in_Arkansas . What's the correct XPath?

Thanks in advance!

Code snippet:

```
            print 3.1, tree.xpath('//*[@id="mw-content-text"]/div[2]')
            print 3.2, tree.xpath('//*[@id="mw-content-text"]/div[2]/table')
            print 3.3, tree.xpath('//*[@id="mw-content-text"]/div[2]/table/tbody')
            print 3.4, tree.xpath('//*[@id="mw-content-text"]/div[2]/table/tbody')     
            print 3.5, tree.xpath('//*[@id="mw-content-text"]/div[2]/table/tbody/tr/td/div/ul/li/a/text()')                           
            for row in tree.xpath('//*[@id="mw-content-text"]/div[2]/table/tbody/tr/td/div/ul/li/a/text()'):
                print row
                district_urls.append('http://en.wikipedia.org'+row.get('href'))
```

As a reference:

```
3.1 [<Element div at 0x1109f7f00>]
3.2 [<Element table at 0x1109f7f00>]
3.3 []
3.4 []
3.5 []
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you've been creating this XPath expression using Firebug or similar developer tools. They work on the DOM which requires `<tbody/>` tags around `<tr/>`s, to these get inserted if not given in the source code. When looking at the page source (**not** using Firebug, if necessary use `wget` or `curl`), you will realize there are no `<tbody/>` tags.

Use this expression:

```
//*[@id="mw-content-text"]/div[2]/table/tr/td/div/ul/li/a
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
//*[@id="mw-content-text"]/div[2]/table/tr/td/div/ul/li/a/text()
```

Comment: Did not work. I posted some output and you can see that beyond the table object, I cannot access any of the content.

Comment: Post updated with the help of Jens Erat's reminder about firebug.